# How can I add a fixed width to this mansory grid

Tags: javascript, masonry

I have very similar layout like this using mansonry.js

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrVGox

But I am having trouble understanding how to make the grid with a fixed width of 1000px

```
.grid {
  background: red;
  /* center */
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Adding max-width: 1000px; breaks the grid items to fall out the the grid or adding width: 1000px; does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

Css margin bottom

```
.grid-item {
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
    /* vertical gutter */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #D26;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 160,
    gutter: 20
});
```

Comment: but how can I preserve the feature of **fitWidth: true** from masonry.js, It allows the centering the grid items when shifting the items